# How to generate a deck of cards in Python

Tags: python

How do you generate a full deck of 52 cards the most efficiently in list format in Python so that the list will look like this:

`['1 of Spades', '1 of Hearts', '1 of Clubs', '1 of Diamonds', '2 of Spades', '2 of Hearts'` etc.

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer the following code, as in Python `Readability Counts`

```
>>> faces = range(2,11) + ["King","Queen","Jack","Ace"]
>>> colour = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"]
>>> from itertools import product
>>> ["{} of {}".format(*card) for card in product(faces, colour)]
```

Comment: using `["{} of {}".format(f, c) for f, c in product(faces, colour)]` is just as complicated as the first answer, in my opinion, if not more as there is an imported module to contend with.

Comment: That only gives twelve cards per suit, and the lowest value of a suit is `2`, and the face cards are not correctly ordered... but otherwise this looks pretty good :-)

Comment: @DavidK.: an imported module isn't something you have to "contend with".  Modules are where Python stores its functionality.

Comment: @DSM by 'contend with' I mean that you need to research parts of the module before you can understand its proper use, whereas a for loop would do the same in this answer's case making the module unnecessary for this example

Comment: @DavidK. itertools is so freaking incredible, I think everyone needs to learn it. Look at that answer. It's so clean and neat. So pythonic

Comment: @DavidK.: I would disagree. A language is not about syntax, its about the batteries. Moreover `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.`, so if your case can be satisfied with a library function, prefer it, rather than to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I think this is a terrific answer. Nice, clean, and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

To easily (and efficiently) generate a deck of cards in a list format you can type:

`deck = [str(x)+y for x in range(1,14) for y in ["S","H","C","D"]]`

-

When you `print(deck)` you will get an output like this:

`['1S', '1H', '1C', '1D', '2S', '2H', '2C', '2D', '3S', '3H', '3C', '3D'.....`

-

To change the output from `"3C"` to something like `"3 of Clubs"`for example, then change

`["S","H","C","D"]` to `[" of Spades"," of Hearts"," of Clubs"," of Diamonds"]`

-

This will make your list look like: `['1 of Spades', '1 of Hearts', '1 of Clubs', '1 of Diamonds', '2 of Spades', '2 of Hearts'.....` and so on.

-

*Note: The initial example is probably the shortest that you can get it...*

Comment: I think the big men in suits will have some words with you if you play a 13 of Spades..

Comment: This could be useful if you want to reference image names as well, ie. `13C.jpg` or `8D.gif` etc.

Comment: Storing " of Spades" instead of just "Spades" is IMHO ugly. And then you have the problem DSM pointed out. If you need some kind of card ID, then you should solve this using some other method.

Comment: @DavidK.: I would suggest you to grab a good Python book, or read the entire Python tutorial. You will then understand the huge resources the libraries contain. As others have said, `itertools` is an awesome library, and the more you learn about it the more you would love it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs']
>>> faces = ['ace'] + range(2, 11) + ['jack', 'queen', 'king']
>>> deck = ['%s of %s'%(f, s) for f in faces for s in suits]
```